# Outlook on the web (outlook.com) no longer displaying images. How can I restore that functionality?

Tags: google-chrome, email, microsoft-outlook, browser, images

#### Context

All was fine until recently and Microsoft did something, probably for "security" reasons, namely every time I click on an email, none of the images show.

To replicate, I use Google Chrome on Windows 10. I open up my outlook account and click on an email in my inbox, though could be anywhere else.

Here is an example using a Disney Movie Insiders email:

[image: Outlook.live.com not showing images]

#### What I've tried

Here are troubleshooting steps taken:

- Under Settings (gear top right area) → View all outlook settings → Junk email → Filters

  - I unchecked the box for "Block attachments, pictures...".
- The checkbox for "Only trust email from addresses in Safe senders..." is unchecked.
- In Mail → Layout → Sender image"

  - I see the "Show sender images" radio button has the check.

I am not interested in adding every email address/domain to safe senders, nor did I check if that resolves the issue. I have the two checkboxes unchecked, so that should take care of junk email reasons.

#### Question

How can I show images again in my e-mails on outlook.com without adding  every email address/domain to the safe senders list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a recent outlook.com issue, according to [this thread](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/outlook/outlook-live-com-not-showing-external-images-in-messages/m-p/2763629) (found by doing a websearch for "outlook.com does not show images"):

> **outlook.live.com not showing external images in messages**
>
> I can't get outlook.live.com to show images.
> ...
>
> Up to a few weeks ago, things were fine. But now mailing lists that I
> subscribe to (like Harbor Freight Tools advertisements, or The Wall
> Street Journal, or Redfin search matches, or ...) aren't showing
> images. This makes email pretty much unusable, since there's no UI to
> explicitly allow images for that email message.
>
> I've added the email sender to my contacts and to safe senders. The
> mailing list is known to Outlook in the options -- seems like that's
> allowed, too.
>
> ...
>
> How can I get images to load? Why did they break?

In that same thread a [workaround is given](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/outlook/outlook-live-com-not-showing-external-images-in-messages/m-p/2771760/highlight/true#M8172) (bolding mine):

> same problem here.
> ...
> **enable conversations and the images will show**
> ...

[This article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-how-email-is-displayed-in-outlook-on-the-web-57fe0cd8-e90b-4b1b-91e4-a0ba658c0042) explains how you can enable conversation view:

> 1. At the top of the page, select Settings Settings to open Quick
>    settings.
> 2. Under Conversation view, choose one of the following:
>
>    - To sort messages by conversation, select Newest messages on top or Newest messages on bottom.
>    - To show email as individual messages, select Off.

Or if you're using classing Outlook on the web:

> 1. At the top of the message list, select Filter.
> 2. Select Show as > Messages or Conversations.

Comment: That was not obvious to enable conversation view, nor should that be necessary. I would have to research exactly what that does, which in itself says something, but that should have nothing whatsoever to do with images.

Comment: It's definitely not a solution, but a workaround for the time being until Microsoft fixes this issue. I don't understand either why it works, just hope it creates a workable situation for now.